# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'NaiveBayesSentiment' on <module '__main__' from 'app.py'>

Tags: python, pickle

I already run my code to load my variable saved by pickle. This my code

```
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
nb_model = pickle.load(open('model_pickle.pkl', 'rb'))
```

this is a object

```
class NaiveBayesSentiment():

def __init__(self, datasentimen, stopword, norm, datatest):
    self.datasentimen = datasentimen
    self.stop_word = stopword.T.values
    self.norm_words =  pd.Series(norm['kata kbbi'].values,index=norm['kata singkatan']).to_dict()
    self.datatest = pd.DataFrame([datatest], columns=['comment'])
def cleansing_data(self, datasentimen):
            datasentimen = datasentimen.replace('\n', ' ',regex = True)
            datasentimen = datasentimen.str.replace("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ", regex = True)
            datasentimen = datasentimen.str.replace('\s{2,}', ' ', regex=True)
            datasentimen = datasentimen.str.lower()
            return datasentimen
            cleanposdata = cleansing_data(datasentimen[datasentimen['class sentiment'] == 'positif']['comment'])
            cleannegdata = cleansing_data(datasentimen[datasentimen['class sentiment'] == 'negatif']['comment'])  

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

and i get error like this :

```
nb_model = pickle.load(open('model_pickle.pkl', 'rb'))
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'NaiveBayesSentiment' on <module '__main__' from 'app.py'>
```

this is code when I do pickle in python

```
nb_model = NaiveBayesSentiment(datasentimen, stopword, norm, datatest)

with open('model_pickle.pkl', 'wb') as pickle_out:
pickle.dump(nb_model, pickle_out)

with open('model_pickle.pkl', 'rb') as pickle_in:
unpickled_nb_model = pickle.load(pickle_in)

print(unpickled_nb_model.finalclassification())
```

what should i do please helpme

Answer (score 0):

Python's `pickle` serializes data but not classes nor functions. They saved their names only, so classes or functions have same name don't exists when deserialize, occurs error as above. Therefore, also to load pickled objects, same definitions must exist.

**Add:**

This means that `NaiveBayesSentiment` must be defined when call `pickle.load`. In other words, import a module which has `NaiveBayesSentiment`.

Comment: so what should i do can you help me ?

Comment: the naive bayes class doesn't have an import module, that's just my assumption so that the pickle can run but the result is an error ,  what should i do can you help me give some code maybe

Comment: `nb_model = pickle.load(open('model_pickle.pkl', 'rb'))` and `class NaiveBayesSentiment():` are separated? If not, it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: nb_model = NaiveBayesSentiment(datasentimen, stopword, norm, datatest) with open('model_pickle.pkl', 'wb') as pickle_out: 
     pickle.dump(nb_model, pickle_out)

    with open('model_pickle.pkl', 'rb') as pickle_in:
    unpickled_nb_model = pickle.load(pickle_in)

    print(unpickled_nb_model.finalclassification())

this is how i use naivebayerssentimen i declare in pickle